# wordpress next_post_link() only from current child category

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created a custom loop that only displays one post at a time, the navigation between posts is done using `next_post_link()` and `previous_post_link()`.

The problem is that my post hierarchy includes a parent category which is common to many posts, and I want to navigate only to posts in that child category.

The links are enabling navigations between all the posts from the parent category as well.

I've done some research and I can't find a fix for this, any idea?

**Code:**

```
<div class="setas-next">
    <?php previous_post_link('%link', '»', TRUE); ?>
</div>
<div class="setas-prev">
    <?php next_post_link('%link', '«', TRUE); ?>
</div>
```

I'm creating this navigation in both `loop.php` and `loop-single.php`.

Thanks,

Ricardo

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I was working in Wordpress, but I have found that for more complicated pagination needs like this you may be best served working with a WP_Query ( http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query ) to use the exact ids of the Child category you want and then use the post IDs to find the next and previous to the one currently being used.

Mind your edge cases with this, your most recent post in particular is not going to have one more recent ... at least not right away ;)